# Can't access RabbitMQ server even after changing configuration file?

Tags: java, python, rabbitmq, amqp

By following this link

```
http://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html
```

I changed `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config` and added the line

```
[{loopback_users, []}]
```

Now the config file looks like

```
[{kernel, [{inet_dist_use_interface, {127,0,0,1}}]},
{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}, {tcp_listeners, [{"127.0.0.1", 5672}]}]},
{rabbitmq_mochiweb, [{listeners, [{mgmt, [{ip, "127.0.0.1"},
                                       {port, 55672}]}]}]}].
```

Then I restarted my `rabbitmq` server by executing in following order:

```
service rabbitmq-server stop
service rabbitmq-server start
```

Still I am unable to connect to this server remotely (using both Python and Java clients). It gives `connection refused` error.

Comment: ```telnet``` and see if that works. ```telnet yourhost 5672```

Comment: hmm in my configuration I only have `[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}]` and everything works fine, try to remove `tcp_listener` option and see if it works

Comment: Also check you firewall is open for the required ports

Comment: @nafas only having `[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}]` worked! reply as an answer so I can resolve my question

Comment: @Fahad cool mate, did you remove other options or just the tcp_listener?

Comment: i removed other options too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my configuration I only have:

```
[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}]
```

and everything works fine,

try to remove `tcp_listener` option.